# Spring 5 no longer injects a proxy to shared entityManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

```
@Configurable
public Class SomeClass {

        @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
        private EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

In spring 4/ hibernate 4, this code used to inject a proxy that provide access to a shared entityManager (which was created using openEntityManagerInViewFilter), I'm trying to migrate this old code base to use spring 5 / hibernate 5, but spring 5 is injecting an actual entityManager instance instead of a proxy. This manager is application managed and is not being closed at any point and is causing connection leak. How do I get the old behavior back, where spring would inject a proxy instead?

My configuration:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"
                      mode="aspectj" />
<context:spring-configured />
<bean class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="driverClass" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="user" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="${database.minPoolSize}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${database.maxPoolSize}" />
    <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="${database.preferredTestQuery}" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${database.maxIdleTime}" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    id="transactionManager">

    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="corePersistenceUnit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan"
        value="some.packages"></property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jmx.enabled">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```